# How to get the current UAC mode

Tags: c#, .net, uac

Can we check what is the current UAC type set in the device before running the application through C#.

I got to know the approach to check whether the current user is Administrator or not. But, I also need to know the UAC type set (i.e. default/never notify) for some internal logic.

Is it possible? Please help.

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSUACSelfElevation-644673d3 check this out

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to know this. Commonly when people think they want to know this, in fact they don't need to know it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just wanted to know how to get the UAC setting. I saw a post where they mentioned in the registry setting "HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System" we can get to know the UAC mode.

Can someone shown more light in this regard?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Can you please help me get this setting. The actual reason i'm asking is that, i need to uninstall a software. If the software is installed in Admin mode (UAC: Never Notify) and when tried to uninstall in standard user mode, it fails. So, I want to have a logic that checks the pre-requisites before uninstallation.

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way. I won't tell you how to get that information because its the wrong solution to the problem. I recommend that you ask a question about your actual problem, and let us tell you the right solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Thanks for your suggestion. I have posted a new query as you suggested.